# Children’s poem about a boy stuck between the tracks on the underground

Tags: identification-request, poetry

When I was young I used to love Michael Rosen. Don’t put mustard in the custard and lots of silly ones like that. I also remember that there was a darker poem in one of the poem compilation books set on the underground about a boy who fell between the tracks and couldn’t get back up. The train was coming and no one would help him.

Now it’s strange as I can remember a fair bit of the poem (not the name but some of the verses) and I am sure it was Michael Rosen but I can’t find the actual poem anywhere when searching using these specific terms.

> Down down on the underground

> They can’t see me

> But I’m down between the tracks

> And the train is coming

Not in the right order but they get more and more panicked as the trains lights get brighter.

I remember the picture of the poem was a tunnel with shadow grownups on the platform and train lights in the distance.

I think it was in a poem compilation so I would ideally like to find the compilation title it was included in as well as the title of the poem itself.

For reference I would have been reading this approximately 20-25 years ago, in English, in the UK.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This is Michael Rosen's poem "Nightmare", found in his book *Mustard, custard, grumble belly and gravy*, which is available to borrow on the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/mustardcustardgr0000rose/page/n45/mode/2up?q=%22down+between+the+lines%22):

> I'm down
> I'm underground
>
> I'm down the Underground
>
> Waiting
>
> Waiting for a train
>
> There's the platform
> There's the lines
> There's the tunnel
> There's the lines.
>
> I'll wait down there
> Down between the lines
> Waiting for the train
> Down between the lines.
> I'll climb down there
> Down between the lines
> and wait for the train
> down there.
>
> [...]
>
> I'm between the lines
> and the train's coming.
> Can't you see?
>
> [...]
>
> I'm still down
> Can't anyone see me
> down between the lines?
>
> [...]

[image: image from the book]

Interestingly, I found [an article about Mike Rosen's visit to a school](http://booksforkeeps.co.uk/issue/8/childrens-books/articles/other-articles/a-poet-in-school) where he mentioned this very scenario as a recurring boyhood nightmare (probably, based on "I used to have") of his:

> 'Nightmares… do you have nightmares? I used to have one about the underground in London. I'm in the underground, down between the lines. And the platform's getting higher and coming to squeeze me. And I can see a train coming, nearer and nearer. And I'm shouting, "I'm here. Down between the lines. Can't somebody see me?"… '

---

This was quite a tricky one to find, since Google doesn't index this poem at all. I found the above school-visit quote by searching for variants of your phrases, such as "between the rails" or "between the lines" as well as "between the tracks". The query `poem rosen "between the lines" train is coming` got me to that page, but no sign of any poem on the same theme. I was about to post my answer just mentioning that school-visit story, and speculating that maybe you misremembered it as a poem. But if that really was a nightmare of his, it's plausible that he'd turn it into a poem! So I gave up on Google and searched the Internet Archive for the phrase "down between the lines", which got me to the right source finally.

Comment: I applaud your tenacious search skills!

Comment: Amazing - even knowing the poem name it is not easy to find online considering most Google articles point towards Michael Rosens ‘nightmare’ COVID-19 coma. I take my hat off to you!

Comment: Maybe there'll be a new nightmare poem by Rosen, this time with a different kind of tube :)